# XDebug profile directory

Tags: php, debugging, nginx, xdebug

I have nginx server with 3 virtual hosts for different developers. Is it possible to set up xdebug profiler to save profiling files to different virtual hosts directorys? for now, it works with nginx directive `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/path/to/vhost/directory/profiles;\n"`
but is it possible to do this with php.ini settings?

Comment: Using `PHP_VALUE` you override what is there in `php.ini` or define it if it is not defined. So yes you can do this. But why not check first and then ask?

Comment: For now it works with this directive fine. But i think that is very complicated solution. That's why i am asking.

Comment: This directive is specially if you want to set different settings for each of your virtual host. Or instead of being dependent on the config in `php.ini` you make sure that your `nginx` config has it. This makes sure when you move your config to a different machine, it still has a chance to work. Also the config indicates to the user, that this config is of importance. But you still can choose where you want to keep it

Comment: ok, got it, thanks! that is, with this directive I can change any settings of the PHP for any virtual host, right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to